# What does the graph of a car coasting to a stop (in neutral) look like?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

This question came up while sharing a cup of coffee with a friend.  I tried it out in my car on the way home, and it seemed to hang longer at some speeds than others.  So, say I am driving straight at $50\ MPH$ then I let my foot off the gas and shift to neutral until I come to a complete stop.  What speeds does the car slow down at a faster rate?  How would this look plotted?  What other variables change this rate?

Comment: When a car coasts to a stop, it decelerates (accelerates in a direction that slows the car). Acceleration is determined by the forces on the car and the mass of the car. You didn't tell us about either one. So the only kind of answer we will be able to give is general information about the kinds of friction you might expect to find, and how they generally affect a car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowing-down of your car is a function of all the resistive forces acting upon it: that is, all forces that are trying to dissipate the car's kinetic energy relative to the surface of the Earth. Hence, depending on the exact nature of those forces, the slow-down time, and the deceleration profile, can vary.

That said, we can nonetheless come up with some general principles. Three of the most important forces acting to slow a car when "in neutral" are (not necessarily in order of actual strength, but order of them coming to mind):

1. The *air drag* from the car colliding constantly with the air gas in its path - i.e. what produces the "wind" you feel when you put your hand out the window while it's moving,
2. The *rolling friction* or *rolling resistance* of the wheels against the pavement, which is caused by them being elastic if not plastic and so dissipating energy by squeezing and stretching of the materials (think about how a rubber band warms up if you knead it - that warmth is dissipated energy),
3. *Internal friction* between the various parts within your car that the wheels attach to.

*Loosely speaking*, we can model the second two forces mostly by equations of the form

$$F_\mathrm{dissip} = \mu\ F_N$$

where $F_N$ is the *normal force* of the car upon the roadway, created by its weight. For a car on a flat roadway, $F_N$ numerically equals the weight: e.g. for a car of 1 Mg in mass, it's about 9.8 kN. $\mu$ is some constant that depends on the materials, geometry, etc. involved. The total dissipation will just be the sum, so we can think of an overall $\mu$ characterizing the whole car-road system.

The first one, air drag, depends on the speed regime, but we can roughly, again, say that

$$F_\mathrm{drag} = C\ v^2$$

where $v$ is the speed, for some constant $C$. Finally, adding up all the forces, the total retarding force can be considered as

$$F_\mathrm{ret} = Cv^2 + \mu F_N = Cv^2 + \mu mg$$

where $m$ is the car mass and $g$ Earth's surface gravity (9.8 m/s^2). We can then insert this into Newton's second law to derive an acceleration profile, where we've assumed a straight roadway so as to make this a one-dimensional problem:

$$m a_x(t) = -\left(C[v_x(t)]^2 + \mu mg\right)$$

where we've added a negative sign because the car is slowing down, and which in terms of the car's speed $v(t)$ alone, looks like

$$m \frac{dv_x}{dt}(t) = -\left(C[v_x(t)]^2 + \mu mg\right)$$

and transferring the $m$ gives

$$\frac{dv_x}{dt}(t) = -\left(\frac{C}{m} [v_x(t)]^2 + \mu g\right)$$

. To avoid going into too much math, we then toss that into Wolfram Alpha, and we get that

$$v(t) = \sqrt{\frac{\mu m g}{C}}\ \tan\left(\sqrt{\frac{C\mu g}{m}} \left[c_1 m - t\right]\right)$$

as your deceleration profile. Here $c_1$ is something to adjust based on the initial velocity. Now, because $m$, $C$, and $\mu$ depend on the car (and in particular $C$ and $\mu$ are not something I have figures for offhand and would have to be determined by measurement), if we want to "get at the gist" just to see some deceleration profiles, we should adopt some natural units for the problem to make those prefactors go away: namely, we can take $\sqrt{\frac{\mu m g}{C}}$ as a unit of speed, and $\sqrt{\frac{C\mu g}{m}}$ as a unit of time, which we will call respectively $v_n$ (natural speed) and $t_n$ (natural time) for this problem. If we do that, we can simplify the equation to

$$v(t\ \text{[in units of $t_n$]})\ \text{[in units of $v_n$]} = \tan\left(c_1 m - t\right)$$

and setting $t = 0$, we see $c_1 = \frac{\tan^{-1}(v_0)}{m}$ so in terms of $v_0$,

$$v(t) = \tan\left(\tan^{-1}(v_0) - t\right)$$

in those natural units for the given problem. Note even the mass disappears, and hence this is extremely easy! The curve will thus at first start out steeply if the initial speed $v_0$ is high (so that $\tan^{-1}(v_0) \approx \frac{\pi}{2}$ and hence we're close to the asymptote of tangent), and will approach a linear deceleration after it slows down (since $\tan(x) \approx x$ for small $x$). Also, the time needed to stop the car is $\tan^{-1}(v_0)$, after which point we should say $v(t)$ remains at zero indefinitely.

Finally, here are graphs, for a range of speeds from $1\ v_n$ to $5\ v_n$.

[image]